# Perl: How to align different columns according to their size

Tags: perl, alignment

I have file something like this,

```
SR   Name         Rollno   Class

1    Sanjay       01       B
2    Rahul Kumar  09       A
```

Now I need to add "|" between each. So it should look like

```
SR | Name              |Rollno | Class|

1  | Sanjay            |01     | B    |
2  | Rahul Kumar Khanna|09     | A    |
```

I tried this,

```
sub alignment {
    my ( $string ) = @_;

    my $blk_len = 15;   #Assuming some block size.
    my $len = length $string;
        my $right = $blk_len - $len;
        my $string = $string . ( " " x $right );
        return $string;
}
```

But the problem is if the name of the person is big I need to increase the block size so that the "|" could come properly.

The block size will apply to all and I am getting like this

```
SR           | Name               | Rollno        | Class      |

1            | Sanjay             | 01            | B          |
2            | Rahul Kumar Khanna | 09            | A          |
```

UPDATE:

I am using Perl6::form

```
my $text;
        
        foreach my $line (@arr) {
        my ($SR, $Name, $Rollno, $Class) = split (" ", $line);
        my $len = length $Name;
    $text = form 
             '| {||||||||} | {||||||||} | {||||||||} | {||||||||}|', 
                 $SR,           $Name,       $Rollno,     $Class
                print $text;
}
         };
```

Here till now I have done but the name is not comming properly . I have add extra "|" in name for that. Is there any way we can add "|" by calculating length like(below) but geeting error.

```
{||||||}x$len
```

Comment: Try print using [Perl6::Form](https://metacpan.org/pod/Perl6::Form)

Comment: If your original data file has 'Rahul Kumar', where's the 'Khanna' coming from?

Comment: @Shawn that's a example , I don't want to put extra name in 3rd row

Comment: @vkk05 Is there any other way? because I am not able use Perl6::Form.

Comment: @HG: You can also format data using perlform. Here are the useful links [perlform](https://docs.mojolicious.org/perlform), [Perl formats](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlform.html). Do try and let us know if it works for you.

Comment: Assemble  all strings for each a column and find the largest length in each; that'll be your `$right` (number of spaces), for each column.  So you'll need the whole table ahead of time.  Or, use a library (module), and there's a number of them.

Comment: @vkk05 Hey! Can you check the update part.

Answer (score 1):

If that function is being applied to each field you will determine the maximum length for each column and keep an external record of that. That value, along with the field text would need to be feed to the alignment function (changes needed) and the expected right padding could then be produced.

Trying to change your code as little as possible:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my @lines;
my @max;

# Read file line by line.
while (my $line = <STDIN>) {
  next if ($line =~ /^\s+?$/);
  chomp($line);
  my @fields;
  
  # store lines, field by field
  push @fields, split(/\s{2,}/, $line);
  push @lines, \@fields;

  # check for maximum fields length
  for (my $i = 0; $i <= $#fields; ++$i) {
    $max[$i] = length($fields[$i]) if ($#max < $i || $max[$i] < length($fields[$i]));
  }
}

# Format each line
foreach my $line (@lines) {
  for (my $i = 0; $i <= $#{$line}; ++$i) {
    print alignment($$line[$i], $max[$i]) . "|";
  }
  print "\n";
}

# Your function with minimum changes
sub alignment {
  # Added a new parameter
  my ($string, $m_field_size) = @_;
  
  # Determine the blk_len to use. The default value 15 would be better of as a Constant.
  my $blk_len = ($m_field_size > 15 ? $m_field_size : 15);   #Assuming some block size
  my $len = length $string;
  my $right = $blk_len - $len;
  my $string = $string . ( " " x $right );
  
  return $string;
}
```

This is all it is needed.

Answer (score 1):

Please study following approach if it fits your task

- extend string to max length
- split into array based on field lengths
- join array element with *separator*

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my $length = 32;

while( my $str = <DATA> ) {
    chomp $str;
    if ( $str eq '' ) {
        say $str;
    } else {
        $str .= ' ' for length($str)..$length;
        say join '| ', unpack 'a5a13a9a6a', $str;
    }
}

#         1         2         3         4
#1234567890123456789012345678901234567890

__DATA__
SR   Name         Rollno   Class

1    Sanjay       01       B
2    Rahul Kumar  09       A
```

Output

```
SR   | Name         | Rollno   | Class |

1    | Sanjay       | 01       | B     |
2    | Rahul Kumar  | 09       | A     |
```